# Absolutely positioned text does not animate when fading the parent element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, internet-explorer-7

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to create a slideshow that fades slides. There is text overlaid on each slide and this text is absolutely positoned so that it sits partially outside the container.

Everything works in Firefox, Chrome etc but the text does not animate in Internet Explorer 7 or 8.

The container animates like usual but the text just appears and disappears, also it seems to be partially clipped by it's container when animating.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8xvFF/8/

Comment: If one has habit of getting epileptic seizures, I dont recommend looking at the demo :D

Answer (score 0):

Yup it's a bug.

Add

```
opacity:inherit;
filter:inherit;
```

to your `.slide-text` selector.

Fixed sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8xvFF/44/

Comment: Does not appear to be working. Just loaded it in IE7 and the text is cropped when the container animates causing the text to flicker.

Comment: @Camsoft - yeah - seems like in IE9 with browser mode IE7/IE8 the problem gets fixed - I run it now in IEtester and the problem is still there... :/